# How do I hand off my Messenger Bot to Salesforce Live Agent?

Tags: salesforce, facebook-messenger, chatbot, claudiajs

Building a bot using [claudia.js](https://claudiajs.com/) and the client wants in some circumstances to be able to hand off to a Live Agent using the Salesforce [Live Agent](https://www.salesforce.com/products/service-cloud/features/live-agent/) service. I've looked for documentation on how a handoff like this would work and can't find anything. I've also reached out to Salesforce, but they have yet to get back to me. Really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For integration with Salesforce Live Agent you can use REST API.

I'd like to suggest you to start with [Live Agent REST documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_understanding_resources.htm) and then look on [Live Agent Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_dev_guide_API_versions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

For Integration of Salesforce live agent API you can get step by step information [here.](https://www.mobindustry.net/integrating-salesforces-live-agent-into-your-mobile-app/#h_1)

Otherwise you can go for salesforce Live agent [documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/212/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/live_agent_rest.pdf).